# AudioRecorder issue with Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-mediarecorder

I am getting this issue where I am recording the PCM_16_bit audio, with sampling rate of 44.1 kHz.
The raw files that I am getting in the **Lollipop** and **Marshmallow** versions of Android are not the same (I compared the spectrum of the two files using Audacity)
I am running the same app in two different versions of Android OS.
Both the devices are of the same model (Lenovo A7000).

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Are your AudioSource.MIC or do you record from a file etc?

If you are using AudioSource.MIC you would need to be in a very controlled environment to get the same results, I think you'd need to be in a isolated box and have 100% control over voice activity to even get the same results on two recordings on the same OS.

If you are using any other source, like a file/inputstream, you should probably notify android about the issue at the issue tracker. (though this is probably already fixed, after a year?)